# Checking accuracy for multi output regression technique

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, validation

I am looking for different methods to check accuracy for multi output regression model or validation. Here, the problem I am facing is I have more than one output variable say y(as y1, y2, y3) and unable to split it in desirable ratio. And eventually unable to find accuracy for it.

Also, do mention if I am to solve any queries with problem.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: accuracy for regression??? accuracy is used for classification right?

Comment: Yes, it has few Metrics: R-square, AIC, BIC to check accuracy for regression

Answer (score 1):

This is an amazing paper (really short) and in simple English discussing the *possibilities* that can be used to evaluate the performance.

Here is the link: [paper](https://lirias.kuleuven.be/retrieve/584987)

---

#### Paper Summary:

There they discuss:

1. Why simply averaging the results do not help
2. Why comparing the results per target do not help

Both methods are having their dis-advantages. But they conclude with the first method of aggregating the results.

They propose the method called: Rank based aggregation where we take the rank of the scores (RRMSE, RMSE etc.) and then going for the average across the targets. By doing so you can overcome the issue of non-commensurability of the scores corresponding to different targets.

#### Here in sklearn:

When we are using the MTR techniques such as `RegressiorChain` or `MultiOutputRegressor` *(by checking the source code)* you will see that they simply stack the models together and train them according to their respective method.

But when we *go for checking the score* such as *R2*, *RMSE* etc. they simply ***average the results***. Thus, sklearn itself uses the average results.

Please have a look at the paper for more information.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

you can take advantage of [MultiOutputRegressor()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.html)  and measure the error distance like *Mean Squared Error (MSE)* or *R2_score*, ... for multi-regressions tasks (instead of accuracy) :

```py
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

reg = MultiOutputRegressor(Ridge(random_state=123)).fit(X_train, y_train)

mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, reg.predict(X_test))
print("The mean squared error (MSE) on test set: {:.4f}".format(mse))
```

**Comparison:**

Let's say we have 3 variables:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_linnerud
X, y = load_linnerud(return_X_y=True)

y        #y1,   y2,   y3
#array([[191.,  36.,  50.],
#       [189.,  37.,  52.],
#       [193.,  38.,  58.],
#       [162.,  35.,  62.],
#       [189.,  35.,  46.],
#       [182.,  36.,  56.],
#       [211.,  38.,  56.],
#       [167.,  34.,  60.],
#       [176.,  31.,  74.],
#       [154.,  33.,  56.],
#       [169.,  34.,  50.],
#       [166.,  33.,  52.],
#       [154.,  34.,  64.],
#       [247.,  46.,  50.],
#       [202.,  37.,  62.],
#       [176.,  37.,  54.],
#       [157.,  32.,  52.],
#       [156.,  33.,  54.],
#       [138.,  33.,  68.]])
```

I inspired this [post](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_random_forest_regression_multioutput.html#comparing-random-forests-and-the-multi-output-meta-estimator) and create this experiment which output this plot to compare `RandomForestRegressor()` with `MultiOutputRegressor(RandomForestRegressor())` for two targets which possibly can plot for all 3 targets using 3D plots too.

[image: img]

The full code for this experiment:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor


# Create a random dataset
rng = np.random.RandomState(1)
X = np.sort(200 * rng.rand(600, 1) - 100, axis=0)
y = np.array([np.pi * np.sin(X).ravel(), np.pi * np.cos(X).ravel()]).T
y += 0.5 - rng.rand(*y.shape)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=400, test_size=200, random_state=4)

# Build multi-reg using RF-reg
regr_multirf = MultiOutputRegressor(RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, max_depth=30, random_state=0))
regr_multirf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Build simple/single RF-reg
regr_rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, max_depth=30, random_state=2)
regr_rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict on new data
y_multirf = regr_multirf.predict(X_test)
y_rf = regr_rf.predict(X_test)

# Plot the results
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
s = 50
a = 0.4
plt.scatter(y_test[:, 0],    y_test[:, 1],    edgecolor="k", c="y", s=s, marker=".", alpha=a, label="Data")
plt.scatter(y_multirf[:, 0], y_multirf[:, 1], edgecolor="k", c="g", s=s, marker="o", alpha=a, label="Multi RF score=%.2f" % regr_multirf.score(X_test, y_test))
plt.scatter(y_rf[:, 0],      y_rf[:, 1],      edgecolor="k", c="c", s=s, marker="^", alpha=a, label="RF score=%.2f" % regr_rf.score(X_test, y_test))

plt.xlim([-6, 6])
plt.ylim([-6, 6])
plt.xlabel("variable (target) 1")
plt.ylabel("variable (target) 2")
plt.title("Comparing random forests and the multi-output meta estimator")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```